# How to add to git index with JBoss Tools

Tags: eclipse, git, openshift, jboss-tools

I've created a new project on OpenShift and cloned it locally. But now i'm having problems adding new files and folders to git index. Right click on the new folder (with files and subfolders) in project explorer and choosing Team -> Add to Index, changes nothing. And if i try to commit, Eclipse says that there aren't any changes... (If i only update existing files, everything seems to be fine).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was (kind of stupid though). The folder that contained new content was listed in .gitignore ... but that file isn't accessible through eclipse, i had to look it up on filesystem. I also don't have a clue, how that line came to .gitignore...
Well, that's it...

Comment: In the Package Explorer view and Project Explorer view, you can click on the small caret in the top-right corner, then click on "Filers..." and uncheck the "*. resources". The .gitignore file will become visible in the project explorer (along with all other .* files)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the "Git Staging" view open, and right click on the file in your Unstaged Changes and Select "Add to Index", also make sure that the file is not empty, it did not show up as a staged file until after i added some content to it, even after I had added the file. (Can't add empty files or directories to git with EGit maybe?)

Comment: ... opened Git Stagging view, but there are no files listed there, even after "Add To Index". 
Files are not empty (its a folder with subfolders and files with support for mysql in sails framework - sails-mysql - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like EGit missing new files. I'd love to know a bit more about your setup: 
Where did you clone to, where is your Eclipse workspace?
To make sure your git setup is right I suggest that you do the same with the git command line:

`cd [git-repo]
git status`

Git status should list the new files and tell us that they're not added yet. If they get listed, then we know that your git is set up right and we can get back to Eclipse to try to figure out what's wrong with it.